# how to upload image in cakephp2.5+ and store it in webroot folder

Tags: cakephp, image-uploading, cakephp-2.3

my controller

```
public function add() {

    $this->helpers = array('TinyMCE.TinyMCE');
    $this->layout = 'adminpanel';
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Tour->create();
        if ($this->Tour->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your possstt has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'admin','action' => 'tour'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your schedule.'));
    }
```

my view file

```
echo $this->Form->create('Tour');
echo $this->Form->input('vartitle',array('class' => 'form-control','label' => 'Tour Title'));
// etc.................
echo $this->Form->input('varbigimg', array('type' => 'file'));

echo $this->Form->end('Save Post',array('class' => 'form-control'));
```

I already check model because image name are stored in database but I want to use that image. I want to save that image in any folder so help me. I am using new version thanks

So tell me how to store image in webroot folder and just save name in database field varbigimg field. I also want to display it on page too. So please solve my problem thanks

I am new in cakephp thanks

Comment: This question reads as if you want someone to write the code for you.  Try framing it with a SPECIFIC question about a problem you're having along with details of the error, or item you don't understand...etc.  What have you tried so far?  What worked, what didn't...etc.  There are SO many resources on this topic online, that this isn't the place for a general "how-to".

Comment: i am trying too much in this topic and not getting any solutions so thats y i post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following

```
echo $this->Form->create('Tour',array('autocomplete' => 'off','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));
```

Allows image/video data to be processed.

Inside controller

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

    if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Tour']['varbigimg']['tmp_name']))
    {
        $fileNameFull = $this->request->data['Tour']['varbigimg']['name'];

        $oldFile = '../../app/webroot/img/'.$fileNameFull; 

        move_uploaded_file(
          $this->request->data['Tour']['varbigimg']['tmp_name'],
          $oldFile
        );

        $this->Tour->create();
        $this->request->data['Tour']['varbigimg'] = $fileNameFull;
```

//HERE you need to specify same for thum

```
        $this->request->data['Tour']['varthumimg'] = $fileNameFull;
```

////HERE you need to specify same for thumbfield

```
        if ($this->Tour->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your possstt has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'admin','action' => 'tour'));
        }

    }
}
$this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your schedule.'));
```

//**Update**

//Specify input type in your code explicitely here.

```
echo $this->Form->input('vartitle',array('type'=>'text','class' => 'form-control','label' => 'Tour Title'));
```

Comment: thanks for reply . but when i am pastethis code that time i face } error 

syntax error, unexpected '{' 


if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Tour']['varbigimg']['tmp_name'])
    {  

so this bracket error plz i am trying but cant. get it. thanks for this suggestions . plz solve 1 last thanks

Comment: @newsurt , check now , one ( was missing

Comment: thanks again i got sql error 
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

Array to string conversion [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php, line 1009]

Comment: after this `$this->request->data['Tour']['varbigimg'] = $fileNameFull;` , use 'print_r($this->request->data['Tour']['varbigimg']);` , What value u get , update answer .

Comment: my image store in my folder but my data not save in db it say 
array to string converstion.
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'  

'34', 'Screenshot from 2014-09-17 17:16:36.png', Array)

1 thing i dont mention is i pass 2 images. in this form

Comment: dude , properly paste your .ctp code here by updating question ,  just `...etc` wont work . :) you should hav specified You use 2 images :)

Comment: schedule.png
 i got image name in print
varthumimg i also pass with varbig image thanks :)

Comment: k sorry for that :) and thanks for awesome suggestions and reply..

Comment: For now check updated code . And do same for thumb img , for that you may use your own logic like changing thumb image path

Comment: vartitle' vardeparts`, `varimgtitle`, `varcolor`, `varbigimg`, `varthumimg`

so 2 image field  varbigimg varthumimg  thanks .

Comment: you are awesome man i hide 1 image field and its work fine :) thanks now last how i display this image in page :) hmm so give me retrive full image path link :) thanks

Comment: when you want to display image in page? After add ? i mean on Listing/index page?

Comment: <img src="/project/app/webroot/img/<?php echo $tours['Tour']['varbigimg']; ?>" yeh i got the image but some image are displaying big so is there any way to view them in fix size.i think i need to use jquery.? thanks. plz tell me thanks again :) (Y) :) you made my day. you save my lots of hours :)

Comment: can you plzpostthe new question related to it, ?Since it solved your issue  and this is other issue , you should make new question,i wil upvote u so you will also.And u  can accept it as answer.Good 4 both

Comment: now for this image. how to display uploaded image thumb in form. as well what to write in edit view. thanks. :)

Comment: @newsurt : can you plzpostthe new question related to it, ?Since it solved your issue and this is other issue , you should make new question,i wil upvote u so you will also.And u can accept it as answer.Good 4 both

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601570/after-uploading-image-i-want-to-make-thum-image-as-well-as-edit-image-in-form 
ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Man , i get to you the needs to make it simply.
First you need access the file in your controller, using $this->data['Tour']['varbigimg'];
ok , it's your file.
Ok, now you need send this file to webroot, you can use File Class of the cakephp 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html
You can move and copy files to webroot using WWW_ROOT constraint, this constant get to you the correct path to webroot folder, if u need send to webroot img use IMAGES constant.
Using, Folder/File and cakephp constants it's very easy to make your needs.
If you need a more information about this, plz ask me and i create a real example to you.
Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your uploaded file to a folder. Get the file info of your `$this->request->data` and move to a folder in `webroot`.

There are many plugins for that. Like: [Upload Plugin 2.0](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload)