# multiple image editing error in my cakephp project. cakephp2.5

Tags: cakephp, edit, image-uploading

when i update all 3 images then it will work fine. 
if i dont update all 3 then its work fine . but it will not work if i update 1 and not other. even it will not work if i update 2 and not 1 . may be its my if else cond. error. but i cant fig it out. so plz help me thanks :)

public function edit($id=2) {

```
$this->helpers = array('TinyMCE.TinyMCE');
$this->layout = 'adminpanel';
if (!$id) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
}

$this->layout = 'adminpanel';
//save data
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {

    $this->Home->id = $id;

    //Save image
    if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_1']['tmp_name']))
    {

            $fileNameFull = $this->request->data['Home']['image_1']['name'];

                 $uploadFolder = "upload";
                 //full path to upload folder
                $uploadPath = WWW_ROOT . $uploadFolder;
                $oldFile = $uploadPath.'/'.$fileNameFull; 

            move_uploaded_file(
              $this->request->data['Home']['image_1']['tmp_name'],$oldFile
            );

            $newFile = WWW_ROOT.'courseImages/thumb/'.$fileNameFull; 

            $image = new ImageResizeComponent();
            $quality = 100; // image resize for thumb
            $height = 40;
            $width = 60;
            $this->ImageResize->resize($oldFile, $newFile, 60,60,$quality);
            $this->request->data['Home']['image_1'] = $fileNameFull;

        } 
         if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_3']['tmp_name']))
    {

            $fileNameFull = $this->request->data['Home']['image_3']['name'];

                 $uploadFolder = "upload";
                 //full path to upload folder
                $uploadPath = WWW_ROOT . $uploadFolder;
                $oldFile = $uploadPath.'/'.$fileNameFull; 

            move_uploaded_file(
              $this->request->data['Home']['image_3']['tmp_name'],$oldFile
            );

            $newFile = WWW_ROOT.'courseImages/thumb/'.$fileNameFull; 

            $image = new ImageResizeComponent();
            $quality = 100; // image resize for thumb
            $height = 40;
            $width = 60;
            $this->ImageResize->resize($oldFile, $newFile, 60,60,$quality);
            $this->request->data['Home']['image_3'] = $fileNameFull;

        } 

      if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_2']['tmp_name']))
    {

            $fileNameFull = $this->request->data['Home']['image_2']['name'];

                 $uploadFolder = "upload";
                 //full path to upload folder
                $uploadPath = WWW_ROOT . $uploadFolder;
                $oldFile = $uploadPath.'/'.$fileNameFull; 

            move_uploaded_file(
              $this->request->data['Home']['image_2']['tmp_name'],$oldFile
            );

            $newFile = WWW_ROOT.'courseImages/thumb/'.$fileNameFull; 

            $image = new ImageResizeComponent();
            $quality = 100; // image resize for thumb
            $height = 40;
            $width = 60;
            $this->ImageResize->resize($oldFile, $newFile, 60,60,$quality);
            $this->request->data['Home']['image_2'] = $fileNameFull;

        } 

            else{//Img not uploaded

 //**TWO GOLDEN LINES OF YOUR LIFE**

 $tourForImg = $this->Home->findByid($id);
 $this->request->data['Home']['image_1'] = $tourForImg['Home']['image_1'];
 $this->request->data['Home']['image_2'] = $tourForImg['Home']['image_2'];
 $this->request->data['Home']['image_3'] = $tourForImg['Home']['image_3'];

 //**TWO GOLDEN LINES OF YOUR LIFE**
```

}

```
    if ($this->Home->save($this->request->data)) {              
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to hppp,ee your schedule.'));

    //Save image
    $this->Session->setFlash('Your home slider image  has been saved343434.', 'default',array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));

    //$this->Session->setFlash(__('Your home has been updated.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'homes','action' => 'edit'));    
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your Tour.'));
    }
}
$home = $this->Home->findByid($id);
if (!$home) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
}
if (!$this->request->data) {
    $this->request->data = $home;
}
```

}

```
echo $this->Form->create('Home',array('autocomplete' => 'off','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));
```

echo $this->Form->input('image_1', array('type' => 'file'));
// then display images

//above  same for 3 image

```
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
```

echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use AND operator

```
if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_1']['tmp_name']) &&
   is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_3']['tmp_name']) &&
   is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_2']['tmp_name'])
  )
{
 //HERE Code FOR ALL 3 IMAGES u You have written in the above code WHOLE CODE
//Save image

        $fileNameFull = $this->request->data['Home']['image_1']['name'];

             $uploadFolder = "upload";
             //full path to upload folder
            $uploadPath = WWW_ROOT . $uploadFolder;
            $oldFile = $uploadPath.'/'.$fileNameFull; 

        move_uploaded_file(
          $this->request->data['Home']['image_1']['tmp_name'],$oldFile
        );

        $newFile = WWW_ROOT.'courseImages/thumb/'.$fileNameFull; 

        $image = new ImageResizeComponent();
        $quality = 100; // image resize for thumb
        $height = 40;
        $width = 60;
        $this->ImageResize->resize($oldFile, $newFile, 60,60,$quality);
        $this->request->data['Home']['image_1'] = $fileNameFull;


        $fileNameFull = $this->request->data['Home']['image_3']['name'];

             $uploadFolder = "upload";
             //full path to upload folder
            $uploadPath = WWW_ROOT . $uploadFolder;
            $oldFile = $uploadPath.'/'.$fileNameFull; 

        move_uploaded_file(
          $this->request->data['Home']['image_3']['tmp_name'],$oldFile
        );

        $newFile = WWW_ROOT.'courseImages/thumb/'.$fileNameFull; 

        $image = new ImageResizeComponent();
        $quality = 100; // image resize for thumb
        $height = 40;
        $width = 60;
        $this->ImageResize->resize($oldFile, $newFile, 60,60,$quality);
        $this->request->data['Home']['image_3'] = $fileNameFull;


        $fileNameFull = $this->request->data['Home']['image_2']['name'];

             $uploadFolder = "upload";
             //full path to upload folder
            $uploadPath = WWW_ROOT . $uploadFolder;
            $oldFile = $uploadPath.'/'.$fileNameFull; 

        move_uploaded_file(
          $this->request->data['Home']['image_2']['tmp_name'],$oldFile
        );

        $newFile = WWW_ROOT.'courseImages/thumb/'.$fileNameFull; 

        $image = new ImageResizeComponent();
        $quality = 100; // image resize for thumb
        $height = 40;
        $width = 60;
        $this->ImageResize->resize($oldFile, $newFile, 60,60,$quality);
        $this->request->data['Home']['image_2'] = $fileNameFull;

 //Here 3 img 
}

else if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_1']['tmp_name']) &&
        is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_3']['tmp_name']) 
  )
{
 //HERE Code FOR `image_1` AND `image_3`
}

else if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_1']['tmp_name']) &&
        is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_2']['tmp_name'])
  )
{
 //HERE Code FOR `image_1` AND `image_2`
}
else if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_3']['tmp_name']) &&
        is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_2']['tmp_name'])
  )
{
 //HERE Code FOR `image_3` AND `image_2`
}
else if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_1']['tmp_name']))
{
 //HERE Code FOR `image_1`
}
else if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_2']['tmp_name']))
{
 //HERE Code FOR `image_2`
}
else if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_3']['tmp_name']))
{
 //HERE Code FOR `image_3`
}
else{//Img not uploaded
 //HERE YOUR part You had WHEN image is NOT Uploaded
}
```

**//Updated as per Your issue->**
SEE , check 1st ELSE IF :

```
else if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_1']['tmp_name']) &&
        is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_3']['tmp_name']) 
  )
{
 //NOW u  hav VALUES FOR `image_1` AND `image_3` OK ?  BUT `image_2` val missing.SO set OLD VALUE from database 
 $tourForImg = $this->Home->findByid($id);
 $this->request->data['Home']['image_2'] = $tourForImg['Home']['image_2'];
}
```

Now for next 
    else if(is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_1']['tmp_name']) &&
            is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Home']['image_2']['tmp_name']) 
      )
    {
     //NOW u  hav VALUES FOR `image_1` AND `image_2` OK ?  BUT `image_3` val missing.SO set OLD VALUE from database 
     $tourForImg = $this->Home->findByid($id);
     $this->request->data['Home']['image_3'] = $tourForImg['Home']['image_3'];
    }

DO SAME FOR -> if `image1 is only uploaded` Then set 
OLD values of image2 & image3 from DATABASE

Do same for image2 only uploaded

Do same for image3 only uploaded .

GETTNG? use your own logic dude.

Comment: not getting. i used too much long code. but still errr. in your // part i used full code with if conditon. but still same error..

Comment: Dude what is `errrrr` ? write properly And check updated code , its easy , use logic.`i used too much long code` ,, Then wat should i do ?? You can optimize it . Or should i do ALL for you from coding till optimization ?????

Comment: @newsurt Getting something?

Comment: no. i used as per it but still it same.if i update not then it fine. same happening .nothing to change..

Comment: if i will not update any of images then it display. array to sting..errro.. !

Comment: Show your ctp AND CLEAR YOUR CACHE

Comment: i clear but no effect. plz .i try but cant post here. so plz check mail. .i send you edit function. 
and i got error Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
thanks :)

Comment: @newsurt **//Updated as per Your issue-> SEE , check 1st ELSE IF :** CHECK ANSWER

Comment: thanks i check it for image 1 and 3 and its work fine thanks again :) now i will update for all :) you saved my day :) thnks

Comment: Do u know why There was Array to string ERROR ?

Comment: k thanks :) i think bcz that time other not taking value. or other taking full value image name etc. array mens image have diff. field too. i check it from printr thanks

Answer (score 0):

First use before all if conditions

```
$tourForImg = $this->Home->findByid($id);
```

Use if else loop for each `if` case in this way

```
// for image_1
if(yourconditions for image 1)
{
    // Your code
    $uploaded = true;
}
else
{
    $this->request->data['Home']['image_1'] = $tourForImg['Home']['image_1'];
    $uploaded = false;
}
```

you can also set a variable uploaded to check in end if no image was uploaded at all or you can also set count of images uploaded using `$uploaded ++;`

Comment: use your if condition with else i provided for each image and you will be fine , i am here to  provide just suggestions