# Make Select Options Static to Dynamic

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Select's Option Values are static & i want it dynamic

Right now is static. as per below line

```
<?echo $this->Form->input('intaddressid', 
                            array(
                                'options' => 
                                    array('add1static,add1static' => 'add1static,add1static',
                                          'addres2static,add2stattic'=>'addres2static,add2stattic'),
                                'label'=>false,
                                'empty' => '(Select hotel and time)',
                                'class' => 'form-control border_none'
                            )
                        );
?>
```

My static field output 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6133d4e9aorpo33/Selection_047.png?dl=0

And if i set for each then my dynamic 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3hfhfaubkfr62m/Selection_048.png?dl=0

But i want it only in 1 field all value so help on it

I used for each times as time and my table value generated but now i want this value in above my static code. value => add1,add2 = add1,add2

`$times['Time']['varaddress1']
$times['Time']['varaddress2']`

my updated code is ->

`$arr1=array();`

`$arr2=array();`

`$arr1 = $this->Time->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('varaddress1'),'order'=> array('Time.varaddress1')
    ));`

`$arr2 = $this->Time->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('varaddress2'),'order'=> array('Time.varaddress2')
    ));`

`$finalArr=array_merge ($arr1,$arr2);`

`$this->set('time',$finalArr);`

and in ctp i used

`'options' => $time`

Comment: What is this dude ? `code that generatem y dynamic value` ? please format your question in `proper English` .Else people won't be able to answer your question.Format whole question.And exclude words like thank you etc.Capitalize 1st letter of word in New sentence ,remove all grammatical mistakes Please !!!

Comment: ok check that screen shot :)

Comment: Capitalize 1st letter of word in New sentence ,remove all grammatical mistakes Please !!!

Comment: ok done. check it. are you understanding my problem ?.!

Comment: Select is NOT a text field sir :( .Select is dropdown. You are making questino messy for people tounderstand. :( so noone can answer.Also format your code. :( I had to format your code.

Comment: WHY are you changing Question title all over again ????? I edited title to make question clear,and you are changing it to Your old ,misunderstanding , confusing,grammatically incorrect Title ????? WHY? I just dont get it. YOUR old question Title : `Make Select Text Field Option Value As....` , Dude , Select is 
NOT a text field , ITS drop down .

Comment: Hi You ask NEW Specific question Give title=>"Virtual field is not working" . And ask Question properly with New code wit virtual field.And ask properly please with Clear specification.You will get answer.Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837422/how-to-set-dynamic-url-in-cakephp2-5-project-conroller-action-to-project-dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ctp

```
               <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('intaddressid', array(
                    'options' => $courseCategoriesNames,
                    'empty' => '(choose one)',
                    'label' => false
                    ));
                ?>
```

**UPDATED solution**

In controller:

**NEW**

```
$arr1=array();
$arr2=array();

    $arr1= $this->Course->CourseCategory->find('list',
                                                        array('fields'=> array('Time.varaddress1'),
                                                              'order'=> array('Time.varaddress1')                                                                                                                                                                                                    )
                                            );


$arr2= $this->Course->CourseCategory->find('list',
                                                        array('fields'=> array('Time.varaddress1'),
                                                              'order'=> array('Time.varaddress2')                                                                                                                                                                                                    )
                                            );

    $finalArr=array_merge ($arr1,$arr2);
    $this->set('courseCategoriesNames',$finalArr);
```

**FINAL ans**
//INSIDE model Your Time->

```
public $virtualFields = array('name_price' => 'concat(Time.varaddress1, "-", Time.varaddress2)');
```

////INSIDE model

```
$products=$this->Product->find('list',array('fields'=>  $this->Time->virtualFields['name_price'] )));
$this->set('products',compact($products));
```

Comment: hi ok check my updated code. thanks. it still display varaddress1 only.! but i want var1,var2 in select option.

Comment: Do u have Multiselect Dropdown?

Comment: @newsurt , First Tell me are you getting ALL values in dropdown like you wanted ??? from both Fields?? So ur issue is 2 OPTIONS in Multiselect Dropdown should be selected only  . Correct??????????

Comment: like i want first option var1,var2 and 2nd option 2nd field of table var1,var2 same third option va1,var2 3rd row of table. 
like i want row of table in 1 option.

Comment: oh now i am getting varaddress1 list then varaddress2 list. below. but i want var1,var2  simply i want full row of table in 1 field. and full row of table in 2nd field. same as all

Comment: oh means select value.  like in option what i want 
 <option >dynamice varadd1,varadd2</option>

Comment: now i got 
<option>var1  value </option>
<option>var2 value </option>

Comment: You want to combine Both fields in one <option>F1,F2 </option>   correct

Comment: BUT WHERE , WHEN DID YOU WRITE THIS THING IN YOUR QUESTION ?????? YOU ASK WRONG QUESTION .THERE IS NOTHING LIKE THAT IN YOUR DESCRIPYION ,THAT U want `<option>f1,f2</option>`

Comment: k sorry for that tell me about that..!! :( :D

Comment: @newsurt check final answer

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Time.name_price' in 'field list'

Comment: did u write `public $virtualFields = array('name_price' => 'concat(Time.varaddress1, "-", Time.varaddress2)');` Inside model??

Comment: @newsurt Check answer again

Comment: ya i used it in model and cont. but now working .now i am not getting any value in select !!

Comment: you need to do little R & D on virtual Fields Yourself.Check out on google

Comment: @newsurt Are you mad or what , aressindia.net is my Company's account !!!! Clients send me emails for project.If my company finds External email from some one like you , i will be KICKED out of COMPANY !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  Use nutandevjoshi@gmail.com . And WHO gave you my aressindia.net Email id ????????????

Comment: k sorry for that and delete personal info.

Comment: @newsurt , Where did you get aressindia.net email id ? Where  in personal info you saw ? Give me link.

Comment: i get it form you login -reg code. in that you added in comment.and solve my virtual field error plz

Comment: `login -reg code.`? what is -reg ?? Give link of it.

Comment: hi. are you give it me on fb msg  in that i found in comment . ok forget  it and sorry for that